# Is there a way to convert files from YUV 4:2:0 to MP4 losslessly using ffmpeg on Mac?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm currently working on some image compression research, but I've been having trouble decoding the video for MATLAB. The original files are in *.mkv format from this website: https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/ugc-dataset/original_videos.

At first I tried using a simple copy command like the following:

```
ffmpeg -i original_videos_LiveMusic_360P_LiveMusic_360P-3be0.mkv -c:v copy original_videos_LiveMusic_360P_LiveMusic_360P-3be0.mp4
```

With that, I got the following error:

> [mp4 @ 0x7f932a808200] Could not find tag for codec rawvideo in stream #0, codec not currently supported in container
> Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument

I was able to convert the files to *.avi, but unfortunately these are not readable by MATLAB on Mac OS. I need the video conversion to be lossless, so I can't figure it out. The video codec is YUV 4:2:0.

Thank you for your help, it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: In which containers does MATLAB support uncompressed video?

Comment: It accepts *.mp4 videos or any other video formats with codecs available for QuickTime player (unfortunately very limited), as it uses that to decode them.